# I have converted dll to exe and build then it shows error exe does not contains static main method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace abc
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hallo");

        }
        public static void main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 obj = new Class1();
            obj.display();
        }
    }
}
```

I have created one static method and called in main method to check how dll converted to exe work .

Comment: You need `static void Main` instead of `static void main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry point needs to be called `Main`, not `main`.

That's also in-keeping with .NET naming conventions, which I'd strongly urge you to follow:

- Your namespace should be capitalized, e.g. `Abc` rather than `abc`
- Your `display` method should be called `Display`

Somewhat-conventionally, the class containing the entry point is usually called `Program` too, but that's less of a strong convention. (It's a better name than `Class1` though...)

Most of the time, the compiler doesn't care at all about naming conventions - but in the case of the entry point, the name `Main` is part of the language specification.